# What is more preferable to use combined FK/IK rig or separate rigs?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics

I'm newbie in blender and making my first animation all by myself.
So what will be more user-friendly for me and what are pros and cons overall in both variants?

Comment: Hello, could you please describe your situation? What areyou trying to rig?

Comment: Hi, I'm ringing a character for an NSFW content.

Comment: You should give more details, why would you create a separate rig?

Comment: Sorry if I'm explaining incorrectly, but I need to choose between a rig with an FK/IK switch (that requires to duplicate rigs) or the one that's combines FK and IK without switching. And I'm wondering what is the pros and cons between this two types of rigging ?

Comment: We'd have to know what "combines FK and IK without switching" meant.  It doesn't sound reasonable.  Showing us would probably involve providing a file that did what you were describing, at which point we could tell you why it isn't a good idea (or, stand in awe at the new rigging technique demonstrated.)